Currency refund from bank
Ordered currency from bank in February but it didn’t turn up and bank refunded me. It’s now arrived what do I do?

"It's now arrived" ? You got a box in the mail?  An armoured car backed into your driveway? The bank called to say that the physical notes you asked for were finally delivered?


Ordered currency from bank in February but it didn’t turn up and bank
refunded me. It’s now arrived what do I do?

Contact the bank. That money isn't yours to keep.
They might deduct the money from your account balance, or they might want you to return it. They might even do both, deduct it now, and then remind you that you can deposit it back into your account.
